# Why would the cache_hit in custom reports be zero?

Tags: apigee

I setup a custom report and based on response times, the ResponseCache is working as expected, but when I setup a custom report with cache_hit, there are no hits and hundreds of traffic items. Any ideas on why this might be?

[image]

**Update: I got this working by removing the request url drilldown.**

[image]

Comment: When you say the ResponseCache is working as expected, are you sure that you are getting cache hits? I've seen ResponseCache implementations where the cache key included a timestamp or something that was generally unique, so no cache hits ever occurred. Probably not your issue, but just thought I'd check.

Comment: I've added headers to the output to see if there are cache hits or misses using the cache variables, so I'm pretty sure unless there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Make sure your report is for the right environment (that is, do you have any traffic at all?)

B) Add a second dimension of overall traffic to see the ratio of taffic to cache

C) Add a drilldown to see the resources (are they hitting unique paths each time)

and finally

D) Check your CacheKey Key Fragments to see if you made your cache overly unique so everything gets treated as an invalid cache key.

Comment: I was seeing traffic, but it looks like the issue was that I had used a drilldown for target url (there should have been only one so it wasn't necessary. The total traffic numbers were very low, and cache_hit was showing zero consistently. When I removed that, it seemed to work correctly so I think there is a possible bug where if you use target url, then it only shows UNCACHED requests. My guess would be because there isn't a request for a cached item, there is no target url, and so all cached items are hidden? See image above

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  If there's a Cache Hit there is no Target URL... There's no target at all -- it just skips past it.

Keep in mind that this is true for any variables being set after the Cache on Request and before the Cache on the response.  Say you extract Total Sale from the response -- if you do it within the Cache attachments it will be NULL when the Cache responds.